# CORS support for Rack/Sinatra error responses?

Tags: ruby, rack, cors

I'm writing a web service in Sinatra.  I use middleware to add simple, dumb CORS support (by simply spamming `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` on all requests).  I know there's a gem with more robust support, but this does what I want with 3 lines of code.  Except...

Except that if `@app.call env` raises an exception, I never get a chance to modify the headers.  The exception bubbles all the way up to `Rack::ShowExceptions`, and I can't find a way to inject my extra header into its response.

Do I have to stop using `Rack::ShowExceptions`?  Do I have to mokeypatch it?  Should I put *more* middleware further down the stack that catches non-CORS-aware error messages and adds them?  I'm not sure I know how to do any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I guessed right: I simply had to make sure that `use DumbCorsSupport` was before `use Rack::ShowExceptions`.  It's worth noting, though, that at least in the browsers I'm using, if your 500 page doesn't offer the same CORS headers as the rest of your service, your client-side error callbacks won't get triggered!